# Test multiple states making http requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test my component in ReactJs that should fetch some data from an api.

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const Fetch = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                setState(data)
            });
    }, []);

    const render = () => {
        if (state.length) {
            return state.map(i => <p>{i.title}</p>)
        } else {
            return <p>Loading...</p>
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>List</h1>
            {
                render()
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default Fetch;
```

According to my coponent code:

```js
 if (state.length) {
    return state.map(i => <p>{i.title}</p>)
  } else {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
 }
```

So, the first text that should appear should be `Loading...`, and only after this should appear the list of data from the api.`return state.map(i => <p>{i.title}</p>)`.
My test looks like this:

```js
import {act, render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import Fetch from "./Fetch";

describe('if all is ok', () => {
    test('if the async works', async () => {
        global.fetch = jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve({
            json: ()=> Promise.resolve([{
                body: "est rerum tempore vitae↵sequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores n↵qui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla",
                id: 2,
                title: "qui est esse",
                userId: 1
            }]),
            status: 200
        }));
        await act(async () =>render(<Fetch/>));
        expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(screen.getByText('Loading')).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByText('qui est esse')).toBeInTheDocument();
    })
});
```

So, i expect next things:

```js
 expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(screen.getByText('qui est esse')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Unfortunately i get this:

```js
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: Loading.... This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1>
        List
      </h1>
      <p>
        qui est esse
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Question: How to solve this error which appears when run the test?

Comment: I usually work with jest & enyzme, and not with testing-library, so I might be wrong on this one, but it seems to be that there is not a chance of it displaying 'Loading' since the moment you mount <Fetch /> in your test it calls useEffect and sets the state. Could you try adding a timeout in your mocked promise, but in the same way not blocking the tests from reading 'Loading..' ? Not sure how similar enzyme is to testing-library

Comment: You could also just try rendering the <Fetch /> component as a snapshot and see if there is any instance of 'Loading...' text written in the snap file

Comment: @AntonioErdeljac, could you show how?

Comment: You seem to have asked this twice. I'm not fixing both of them, please delete this one.